# Using Dart Intl how can I initialize multiple libraries?

Tags: dart, internationalization

Using [intl](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl) package how can I initialize multiple libraries. For example I have some translation on `lib1` and other on `lib2`, I would like to initialize both translations so they can be used in my code. Until the moment I have this:

```
import 'package:lib1/_l10n/messages_all.dart' as lib1;
import 'package:lib2/_l10n/messages_all.dart' as lib2;
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:mylib/_l10n/messages_all.dart' as mylib;

main() {
  intl.defaultLocle = 'es';
  await lib1.initializeMessages('es');
  await lib2.initializeMessages('es');
  await mylib.initializeMessages('es');

  print(lib1.helloMessage());
  print(lib2.hiMessage());
  print(mylib.whatUpMessage());
}
```

It only translate `lib1.helloMessage()` since is the first one, the rest of message keep being shown in english.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't work right now. You would have to generate a combined library and use that.